# django autocomplete_light default widget instead of autocomplete widget

Tags: python, django, django-autocomplete-light

I want to create a simple form with a simple input text field that uses **autocomplete** to help users fill out the input field

I'm trying to get **django_autocomplete_light** to work - I followed the instructions closely but the rendered form still has a simple **"dropdown"** (select) menu instead of a **autocomplete** textfield..  (with ALL cities in it which takes a long time to process)

I made all the necessary entries in `settings.py` and `urls.py` and all the javascripts get loaded.

Funny thing: I already got it to work - instead of the **dropdown** menu there was a **textfield** with **autocomplete** functionality - then I tried something else and when I tried the former working solution again it didn't work anymore. I can't find my error :(

This is `autocomplete_light_registry.py`:

```
   import autocomplete_light

   from cities_tiny.models import City

   autocomplete_light.register(City, search_fields=('name','name_ascii'),
       autocomplete_js_attributes={'placeholder': 'city name ..'})
```

This is `forms.py`:

```
from django import forms
import autocomplete_light
from models import Search

class SearchForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        widgets = autocomplete_light.get_widgets_dict(Search)
        model = Search
```

This is `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core import urlresolvers


class Search(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey('cities_tiny.city', null=True, blank=True)


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return urlresolvers.reverse('non_admin:widget_update', args=(self.pk,))
```

It would be OK if this works but I'd rather have JUST the form...
I think I don't need the additional model **"Search"** because I already have **"cities_tiny.city"**.
The form should get its **autocomplete** values from the **"City"** model.

I also found out that I can not use **"CityAutocomplete"** somewhere in the model like in the docs. It always says `KeyError`.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think i found the answer :)

I always got the following message when using registered autocomplete names:

```
KeyError at /search/ 'CityAutocomplete'
```

**localhost:8000/autocomplete/** showed me all the registered autocompletes but nevertheless those autocompletes were unusable

in `forms.py` i had to

```
import autocomplete_light_registry
```

to get rid of the `KeyError`

---

as i mentioned before i got it to work somehow but im quite sure i didn't import `autocomplete_light_registry`
so if someone has a tip where the "real" error lies ... thank you very much